# Secure communication between client and service

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

I have a scenario where I have 2 applications.

1. The service, providing some data
2. The UI client, displaying the data from the service

I want the communication between the service and the client to be secure (encrypted).

What should I use for that? Is the SSL common protocol for such usage, or do we typically use something else?

Comment: Are the service and UI client communicating over a network? What is the threat model? Who is the encryption intended to secure communications from?

Comment: @duskwuff
Yes, its over the network. Threat model is intercepted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your service is exposing a standard REST API (or similar) that your front-end is calling: yes, SSL is the standard. It provides:

- **Confidentiality**: the data is encrypted between the client and the server and cannot be read by an attacker. Typically uses the [RSA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)).
- **Integrity**: an attacker cannot tamper with the messages sent between the client and the server. Typically implemented using [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code?oldformat=true)
- **Authentication**: the client is able to check that the server it is talking to *is* actually yours, and not an attacker. Basically, the server shows to the client a certificate signed by the Certificate Authority having issued the SSL certificate (e.g. VeriSign), that proves its identity.

All that is assuming SSL is configured properly on the server's side: up-to-date ciphers, no support for outdated ones, proper key length (2048 bits or higher), etc.

Note that a *client* can be anything calling your service: a browser-based application, a mobile application, a smart watch application...

You can use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to check if your SSL configuration looks secure.

Comment: You are talking about communication between the Browser and the Service. However, I am talking about the communication between the Client application itself, and the Service. So there should be 2 types of communications here, right? 

1) Browser to UI web application,
and
2) UI web application to some backing service.

I am asking about securing communication 2).

Comment: Apologies if my terminology was confusing. I've edited my answer to make it clearer, but yes, SSL is the standard for any type of client calling your service: browser application, mobile application, ... or even if the "client" is another service calling your service.

Comment: Does that mean that the service will issue SSL certificates to the UI web application?

Comment: No. The Certificate Authority (e.g. VeriSign) is going to give you (or rather, sell you) a certificate, signed with its private key, attesting that your server is the one for the domain your-service.com. When a client connects to your service, the server will send the certificate to him. The client will be able to verify the certificate, making sure that it is talking to your server and not to an attacker. 

A lot of that is transparent, especially the certificate verification part.